# How to change my website's map data image (maybe from knowledge graph) in the search results?

Tags: google-search-console, google-search, schema.org, search-results, json-ld

I'm trying to change the image shown in a website's SERP, when using Google. I installed the JSON-LD Knowledge Graph application script already.

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
      "@context": "https://schema.org",
      "@type": "ImageObject",
      "author": "Georges Jean-Denis",
      "contentLocation": "Montreal Quebec, Canada",
      "contentUrl": "https://lushyne.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/slider_lushyne_1.jpg",
      "datePublished": "2021-02-15",
      "description": "MAIN WEBSITE PICTURE ...",
      "name": "MAIN PICTURE"
}
</script>
```

I get this image when I do this Google search for "lushyne" or click on any of the following links.

[image: luchyne search results showing incorrect map]

- https://www.google.com/search?q=lushyne
- https://www.google.com/search?q=lushyne&rlz=1C1CHBD_enCA940CA940&oq=lushyne&aqs=chrome..69i57.3400j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

But that is not Lushyne from my website.  It is Lushyne, a city in Ukraine. Google tells me so (caption: Map data ©2021 Google.)

That does not work for me. What would you do to make this work?
Do I need to do something with the Google Search Console?

Comment: Are you referring to the large image that rarely appears next to a result, and only in mobile search results? Or about the small favicon that's always shown on mobile and sometimes shown on desktop? Or about a specific rich result type on this list? https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/search-gallery

Comment: I thought Google usually took info from the knowledge graph from Wikipedia, not from markup in your page.

Comment: This is the image :  https://lespointscom.com/a/img/tmp/2021_02_19/lushyne.png

The image is referring to a map data! But it has nothing to do with the website I made!

Answer (score 1):

**[API Google Knowledge Graph](https://developers.google.com/knowledge-graph)** scrapes structured data which in turn for images Google supports for the following types:

- **[Article](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/article)**
- **[Product](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/product)**
- **[Recipe](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/recipe)**
- **[Video](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/video)**

It is not clear from your question what type your image is.
You can use these Google guidelines for your images:

> To non-amp:  For best results, provide multiple high-resolution images
> (minimum of 300,000 pixels when multiplying width and height) with the
> following aspect ratios: 16x9, 4x3, and 1x1.
>
> To amp:  For best results, provide multiple high-resolution images
> (minimum of 800,000 pixels when multiplying width and height) with the
> following aspect ratios: 16x9, 4x3, and 1x1.

There is also an example there:

```
    {
  "@context": "https://schema.org",
  "@type": "NewsArticle",
  "image": [
    "https://example.com/photos/1x1/photo.jpg",
    "https://example.com/photos/4x3/photo.jpg",
    "https://example.com/photos/16x9/photo.jpg"
  ]
}
```

In addition, even if there is structured data consistent with Google's guide, they do not undertake to use this data in a rich result. Check out the **[following Google statement about structured data](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/sd-policies)**:

> **Important: Google does not guarantee that your structured data will**
> **show up in search results**, even if your page is marked up correctly
> according to the Rich Results Test. Here are some common reasons why:
>
> Using structured data enables a feature to be present, it does not
> guarantee that it will be present. The Google algorithm tailors search
> results to create what it thinks is the best search experience for a
> user, depending on many variables, including search history, location,
> and device type. In some cases it may determine that one feature is
> more appropriate than another, or even that a plain blue link is best.
> The structured data is not representative of the main content of the
> page, or is potentially misleading. The structured data is incorrect
> in a way that the Rich Results Test was not able to catch. The content
> referred to by the structured data is hidden from the user. The page
> does not meet the guidelines for structured data described here, the
> type-specific guidelines, or the general webmaster guidelines.

Comment: This is the image :  https://lespointscom.com/a/img/tmp/2021_02_19/lushyne.png

Comment: "It is not clear from your question what type your image is. "
.
The image itself, has this written at the bottom "Map data ©2021 Google"
.